# Solr - Use of Cache in Billion Data

Tags: solr, solr4

We have SOLR storing 3 billions of records in 23 machines and each machine have 4 shards and only 230 million documents have some field like aliasName. Currently queryCache or documentCache or Filter Cache is disable.

Problem: We are trying to get the results which have query like (q=alisaName:[* TO *] AND firstname:ash AND lastName:Coburn) is returning the match documents in 4.3 seconds. Basically we want only those matched firstname and lastname records where aliasName is not empty.

I am thinking to enable filter query fq=aliasName:[* TO *] and not sure it will make it faster as firstname and last name is mostly different in the each queries? how much memory should we allocate for filter query to perform? It should not impact the other existing queries like q=firstanme:ash AND last name:something)

Please don't worry about I/O operations as we are using flash drive.

Really appreciate the reply if you have worked on similar issue and suggest the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to solr documentation...

> **filterCache**
>   This cache stores unordered sets of document IDs that match the key (usually queries)

URL: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache

So I think it comes down to two things:

- What is the percentage of documents that you have with populated *aliasName* ? In my opinion if most documents have this field populated, then the filter cache might be useless. But, if it is only a small percentage of documents, the filter cache will have a huge performance impact, and less memory used.
- What kind of Id are you using? Although I assume that the documentation refers to lucene document Ids, and not solr Ids. But maybe a smaller Solr Ids could result in a smaller cache size as well (I am not sure).

At the end you will have to perform a trial and see how it goes, maybe try on a couple of nodes first and see if there is a performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I will try to use filter cache and see if it will improve the performance.